# Adobe photoshop on ubuntu

Tags: wine, playonlinux, winetricks, photoshop

I've successfully installed photoshop cs6 extended using [this tutorial](http://www.bendangelo.me/install/2014/10/29/installing-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu.html).

My only problem is that I can't drag and drop images in photoshop. Common solutions available online is to uncheck `run as administrator` but I don't know if this will work in playonlinux. Do you guys know how to solve this?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install wine1.8`

Comment: Nope. Still the same.

Comment: The changelog for Wine 1.9.5 mentions improved support for drag-and-drop, install it by running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel`

Comment: Did the command in the previous comment fix you problem?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm using `place` command of Photoshop for importing images. Btw Thank you.